# Adding buttons in TkInter on pressing button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having button and on pressing it I want to create new Button and new Label.

Label must have random color and must change it on pressing this button to another random color.

My code even can not add buttons correctly, there is problems with placing new(sizes are strange).
 How can I improve this? And how can I later create func for new buttons which will change their label's colours, cause I dont have label's names.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

def color(*args):
    pass

def dump( *args):
    global count

    Butt = Button(root, text="color ", command=color)
    Butt.config(width=int(root.winfo_width() / 10), height=int(root.winfo_height() / 10))
    Butt.grid(row=0, column=count)
    Txt = Label(root, text="Color", bg="#" + ("%06x" % random.randint(0, 16777215)))
    Txt.config(width=int(root.winfo_width() / 10), height=int(root.winfo_height() / 10))
    Txt.grid(row=1, column=count)
    count+=1
    root.mainloop()

count=2
TKroot = Tk()
TKroot.title("Hello")
root = Frame(TKroot)
root.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=10)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=10)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=10)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=10)
Butt = Button(root, text="Butt ON")
Butt.bind('<Button-1>', dump)
Butt.config(width=int(root.winfo_width() / 10), height=int(root.winfo_height() / 10))
Butt.grid(row=0, column=0)
Exit = Button(root, text="Quit!", command=root.quit)
Exit.config(width=int(root.winfo_width() / 10), height=int(root.winfo_height() / 10))
Exit.grid(row=0, column=1)
Txt = Label(root, text="This is a label", bg="PeachPuff")
Txt.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1)
TKroot.mainloop()
print("Done")
```

Comment: Don't use `bind` here. Just use `command`. Try this: `Butt = Button(root, text="Butt ON", command dump)`.

Comment: changed,but it is only clear code.no?

Comment: There is no need to bind to a button unless you are doing something other than a simple reference to a function. I am reviewing the rest of your code and I do not see why you are applying height and width to your buttons and also making them expand with the frame. That is counter productive. Do you want them to expand or want them to be a specific size?

Comment: I want to place 1 to 10 buttons and labels which will not cover each other and which will cover all the root in 2 rows.
Event on Butt is adding new Button and new Label in new column

Comment: I can see how you are adding buttons. My question is why are you adding height and with while also adding weights. What is you goal for the button sizes?

Comment: goal is uniform and full covering of window. So I wanted to make for all buttons width= 0.1width of root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few issues with your code.

1st is you are using `place` for your frame.
This is going to cause issues when adding new buttons as it will not allow the window to resize correctly with the new layout.

2nd is how you are writing your code. You name your frame `root` and use the `quit` method on the frame and not on your actually root window. The way you are writing things makes it harder to follow so consider following PEP8 guidelines when writing your code.

3rd you are trying to apply `mainloop` to your frame in the `dump` function. You only ever need 1 instance of mainloop and this applies to the actual root window (`Tk()`).

To address your question on how to change the label color later on I would use a list to store your buttons and labels. This way we can reference their index values and apply your random color code to the labels on button click.

I have re-written most of your code to follow PEP8 and done some general clean up.
Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


def color(ndex):
    button_label_list[ndex][1].config(bg="#%06x" % random.randint(0, 16777215))


def dump():
    global count, button_label_list
    button_label_list.append([tk.Button(frame, text="color", command=lambda x=count: color(x)),
                              tk.Label(frame, text="Color", bg="#" + ("%06x" % random.randint(0, 16777215)))])
    button_label_list[-1][0].grid(row=0, column=count, sticky='nsew')
    button_label_list[-1][1].grid(row=1, column=count, sticky='nsew')
    frame.columnconfigure(count, weight=1)
    count += 1


root = tk.Tk()
count = 0
button_label_list = []
root.title("Hello")
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew', rowspan=2)

tk.Button(root, text="butt ON", command=dump).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
tk.Button(root, text="Quit!", command=root.quit).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
tk.Label(root, text="This is a label", bg="PeachPuff").grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='nsew')

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

A window that can add new buttons and be able to change colors on each label. The main 2 buttons the window starts with are static in that they cannot be pushed out of the window like in you code example and will remain on the left anchored in place.

[image]

Comment: could be using groupbox from label and button better then label and button in list?

Comment: Honestly list are one of the most useful tools in python and personally I have never had a reason to use groupbox and I have always used lists or dictionaries to handle dynamically generated widgets.

Answer (score 1):

below an object oriented version.

Every time you press on Color button, you create a new label and a new button

and put label reference in a dictionary.

The color of the label is randomly generate.

After creation if we click on a new button we change the relative label color.

The coolest part of the script is:

**command=lambda which=self.count: self.change_color(which)**

lambda funcion it's used to keep a reference to the button and label just

create when  we call the change_color function.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,):

        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello World")

        self.count = 0
        self.labels = {}

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.f = tk.Frame()

        w = tk.Frame()

        tk.Button(w, text="Color", command=self.callback).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
        self.f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

    def callback(self):

        text_label = "I'm the {} label".format(self.count)
        text_button = "I'm the {} button".format(self.count)

        color = "#" + ("%06x" % random.randint(0, 16777215))
        obj = tk.Label(self.f, text=text_label, bg=color)
        obj.pack()
        self.labels[self.count]=obj
        tk.Button(self.f,
                  text=text_button,
                  command=lambda which=self.count: self.change_color(which)).pack()
        self.count +=1

    def change_color(self,which):

        color = "#" + ("%06x" % random.randint(0, 16777215))
        self.labels[which].config(bg=color)


    def on_close(self):
        self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```